# Как в ReactJs использовать кнопки типа like-button?

Tags: reactjs

Хочу поместить на страницу [кнопку](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button?locale=en_US), при работе использую React. Попробовал по-простому:

```
<div className="fb-like" data-href="https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/"
                                         data-layout="box_count" data-action="like" data-size="small"
                                         data-show-faces="false" data-share="false"></div>
```

К сожалению, кнопка не отображается, в тоже время в консоли ошибок нет...Как в React Установить данную кнопку?

Comment: Мой хрустальный шар говорит мне что скорее все Вы не различаете html и jsx, и используете className внутри html, а не внутри рендера реактовского компонента.

Comment: Ну или просто не грузите fasebook sdk, в котором по видимому стили этой кнопки тоже зарыты. Попробуйте заменить "className" на просто "class" в первом случае, перечитайте документацию внимательно во втором. Приведите более полный код, если ничего не помогло.

Comment: хрустальный шар вводит вас в заблуждение) у меня есть реактовский компонент, Panel. внутрь этого самого компонента мне нужно поместитть кнопки фейсбука и гуггла. в документации фейсбука пишут class, я же попробовал в ренедере Panel написать код приведенный вв вопросу с  className,не помогло. тогда я нашел это https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-facebook   оно лучше подходит. правда при рендере выскакивает ошибка в GET запросе,который делает компонент этой библиотеки